# Upper Bound on $\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+x\right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}\right)}$

Tags: gamma-function

I am looking for an upper bound on the following ratio of Gamma functions
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+x\right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}\right)}
\end{align}

where $x \ge 0$ (real) and $n\ge 1$ (integer).

Here is the bound I was able to come up with
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+x\right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}\right)} \le \frac{\Gamma \left( \left \lceil \frac{n}{2}+x \right \rceil \right) }{\Gamma \left( \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor \right)}=\frac{\left( \left \lceil \frac{n}{2}+x \right \rceil -1 \right) !}{\left( \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor -1\right)!} 
\end{align}

Comment: You can't do better for an upper bound since you have equality for n even and x an integer.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought too. I wanted to get rid of the floor and ceiling operation what is the best way to do that?

Comment: For the ceiling: note that $\lceil \frac{n}{2} + x \rceil \le \frac{n}{2} + x +1$.

Comment: For the floor, we have $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = \frac{n}{2} +\frac{( -1)^{n} -1}{4}$.

Comment: @Hetebrij Thanks.

Comment: See also [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: @Lucian thanks.